# VB.net on Raspbian OS (Linux & Mono)

Tags: .net, linux, vb.net, mono, raspbian

So I installed mono-runtime and monodevelop on my RasberryPI running Raspbian. I also built a test application in vb.net which Is targeted for .net 2.0. When I try and run the test app I get this:

```
Missing method CompareString in assembly /home/pi/Desktop/PITest.exe, type Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Operators

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

All help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So did you build your application on Mono, or did you copy the binary over from Windows? I wonder whether Mono doesn't have that version of Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Comment: I compiled it in VS on my desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have only `mono-runtime` installed. To support VB.Net, you need an additional package (which contains Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll), it's called `mono-basic` IIRC.

So simple `sudo apt-get install mono-basic` should give you the missing file.

(or was it `mono-vbnc`? <s>Can't check it, sold my raspberry-pi some month ago...</s> Yes, you have to install `mono-vbnc`, too)

Comment: It was mono-vbnc that I was missing. Thanks for all your help!